# Consolidation of reports from two different data sources

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc, report

I'm trying to get data from two different oracle database sources in the form of reports . What I need to do it to take these two reports and do the data comparison . Do you guys suggest any local solution for this about how this can be done?

Comment: Hi this question is too broad.  You can create an symbolic link between two oracle databases, and query the tables from each as though it was a single database.

Comment: From the tags you put on your question, it looks like you want to get data from two databases into Excel, then compare the data. Another approach would be to use SQL to do the comparison, executing the SQL from one of the databases. That would require a "database link" (not a "symbolic link") from one database to the other, which a DBA could provide. More details about the data, the situation and the requirement would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create database link between two databases.

Then You can select your columns and use **minus** to see the difference.

**like this:**

```
select first.a,first.b,...
from your_first_db first
minus
select dblink_db.a,dblink_db.b,..
from your_second_db@db_link dblink_db
```